# How do I deal from a deck array to a player hand array without having duplicates in c++?

Tags: arrays, duplicates, c++14, blackjack

maybe i missed this being answered in another question but after searching i can't seem to find the answer i need.

here is the code i am using to deal cards as it stands which correctly changes the first two card values to random ints from the deck array. however as it is written, the code occasionally passes duplicate values into the player hand.

```
void Deal()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; ++i)
    {
        playerHand[i] = deck[i];
        dealerHand[i] = deck[i + 2];

        if (playerHand[i] == 11)
        {
            cout << "BLACKJACK!! YOU WIN!!" << endl;
            WinHand();
        }

        else if (dealerHand[i] == 11)
        {
            cout << "Dealer Got Blackjack. Hand goes to dealer." << endl;
        }
        else
        {
            playerNextCard++;
            dealerNextCard++;
            deckNextCard = 4;
        }


    }
    for (size_t i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        cout << playerHand[i] << endl;
    }
    cout << "? \n" << dealerHand[1] << endl;
    cout << "Money: " << money << endl;

    return;
}
```

Comment: You need to shuffle deck.

Comment: The deck is shuffelled in a different function. Shuffling the deck doesn't solve the issue. However adding in three variables playerNextCard, dealerNextCard, and deckNextCard I was able to track which card was being dealt and to which position its being dealt to. simply replacing playerHand[i] = deck[i] with playerHand[playerNextCard] = deck[deckNextCard then adding one to each next card every iteration of the loop solved the issue completely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Player, and Dealer are always receiving the first four cards unless an 11 is drawn where it terminates early. Whether, or not the deck is shuffled there is a possibility to receive a duplicate integer. If you want to make each draw integer unique then you can search the deck until the previous one does not match. You will also have to consider what happens if no unique integer is found.

Comment: That is not what your code states. It is checking while you are dealing.
`playerHand[i] = deck[i]; if (playerHand[i] == 11)`